# How to manage url of Hugo site hosting on netlify?

Tags: netlify, hugo, netlify-cms

I am trying to make static pages on a hugo website hosting on netlify using netlify CMS and academic theme.

My aim is:
  example.com/admission

- example.com/admission/
- exapmle.com/admission/success/ or exapmle.com/admission/success.html

So I make pages below:

```
  content
    + admission
       + index.md
       + success.md
```

`example.com/admission/` shows index.md that is I intend.
However `exapmle.com/admission/success/` and `exapmle.com/admission/success.html` both shows 404 page not found.

How to place files to come true my purpose?

---

I changed the file construction:

```
  content/
    + admission/
       + index.md
       + success/
         + index.md
```

And I can see the contents on `exapmle.com/admission/success/`.
Is this the right way?

Comment: Would you be able to post your configuration file? And does it work locally on your machine when you run `hugo server -D`?

Comment: @runar The file is config\_default\config.toml ?

Comment: Yes, this is fine. And you got the result you wanted, no?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your pages are in draft mode, make sure that `draft` is set to false in the page, here is an example:

```
+++
title = "Test"
slug = "test"
draft = "false"
+++
```

Try to run `hugo server` on your local machine and verify, `hugo server -D` is to build drafts

Here is Hogo Forum https://discourse.gohugo.io/, you would get answers much faster if search/post there